# ¿Por qué no me funciona la función sorted?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un reto para la universidad y necesito poner en orden descendente una matriz según su segundo campo, esta es la matriz:

```
 tuplas_verificar = [
        ['sumamente apto ', 105], 
        ['moderadamente apto ', 925], 
        ['marginalmente apto ', 1090], 
        ['no apto ', 1005]]
```

Estoy usando la función Sorted para que se ordene en orden descendente

```
sorted(tuplas_verificar, key=lambda  verificar: verificar[1])
```

en teoría esto me tiene que ordenar la matriz de esta manera:

```
tuplas_verificar = [
        

        ['marginalmente apto ', 1090], 
        ['no apto ', 1005]
        ['moderadamente apto ', 925],
        ['sumamente apto ', 105]]
```

pero simplemente me devuelve la matriz como al inicio, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: agrega el parametro `reverse=True`

Comment: No sirve :'( 
no le hace ningún cambio a la matriz, hay otra manera de darle el orden que necesito???

Comment: nop, y verifica el nombre pues en el sorted usas `tuplas_verificar` pero tu variable se llama `tupla_verificar` (tupla en singular)

Comment: jajajaj si me equivoque en el nombre de la lista pero acá, en el código en visual code esta bien 
pero no me sirve la funcion y ya lo intente de varias formas

Comment: deberías usar sorted(tupla_verificar,key= lambda x: x[1],reverse= True) y debería andar

Comment: claro que no modifica la original, deberías asignarla a un nuevo objeto: nueva= sorted(tupla_verificar,key= lambda x: x[1],reverse= True)

Answer (score 2):

Solución:

```
ordenadas = sorted(tuplas_verificar, key=lambda  verificar: verificar[1])
```

`sorted` **no** ordena la lista; **devuelve** una lista ordenada.

**Demo**

```
tuplas_verificar = [
    ['sumamente apto ', 105],
    ['moderadamente apto ', 925],
    ['marginalmente apto ', 1090],
    ['no apto ', 1005]]
ordenadas = sorted(tuplas_verificar, key=lambda  verificar: verificar[1], reverse=True)
print(tuplas_verificar)
print(ordenadas)
```

produce:

```
[['sumamente apto ', 105], ['moderadamente apto ', 925], ['marginalmente apto ', 1090], ['no apto ', 1005]]
[['marginalmente apto ', 1090], ['no apto ', 1005], ['moderadamente apto ', 925], ['sumamente apto ', 105]]
```

Comment: anuma no me di cuenta, al ejecutarlo en Google colab esos detalles pasan desapercibidos

Comment: Muchas gracias Karnal :3

Answer (score 0):

La función `sorted` genera/retorna un nueva lista con los elementos ordenados, para que la lista modifique el orden de sus mismos elementos sin necesidad de generar una nueva lista, puedes usar el método `sort`. Adicionalmente y siguiendo tu ejemplo original, la corrección sería:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
tuplas_verificar = [
        ['sumamente apto ', 105], 
        ['moderadamente apto ', 925], 
        ['marginalmente apto ', 1090], 
        ['no apto ', 1005]]
tuplas_ordenadas = sorted(tuplas_verificar, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Es importante notar la diferencia de `itemgetter(1)` a `key=lambda  verificar: verificar[1]`. Aunque ambos métodos retornan el mismo resultado, `itemgetter` en términos de rendimiento suele ser mejor, ademas de que es serializable a través de pickle, mientras que lambda no.

> `itemgetter` recibe como argumento el índice del elemento a recolectar a través del método `__getitem__()` y retorna un objeto `callable` que recibe como argumento el contenedor al cual se le va extraer el elemento con el índice proporcionado anteriormente.